# A random forest with one tree performs worse than a single decision tree?

Tags: random-forest, decision-tree

I am analyzing medical data for a hospital study and if I am using a random forest with only one tree then the cross validation scores are quite bad (indicating overfitting) whereas if I am using a decision tree the score values are actually quiet good. Both classifier have the same depth parameter. So how can this behaviour be explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction procedure for decision trees usually includes pruning, which is a part that is done a posteriori in order to reduce the depth and avoid overfitting. Random Forest does not use this method, as it actually takes advantage of the high variance of the overfitted decision trees by averaging them.

Moreover, the decision tree would be built by training on the full dataset, while the "random forest" tree would be build on a bootstrap of the training dataset, which could likely translate into poorer performance since it will be biased towards records that have been included multiple times in the sampling. Again, Random Forest takes advantage of this by averaging over multiple trees, but here it's a disadvantage.

All and all, the difference in performance is not surprising.